# Keep the if statement going

Tags: python, opencv, while-loop, raspberry-pi

I'm programming a script in Python to take a picture with a webcam everytime theres an input on GPIO pin 17. I'm using a while loop and as long as the buttom connected to pin 17 is not pressed, its set to True. If pushed its set to False, and the code starts.

My problem is: The code in the if statement cant finish before the buttom is released and set back to True. So it just stops and shows the picture. Any idea of how i can get the code to finish , and then it returns to state True?

**EDIT**: The if statement runs as long as the button is pushed. When released it stops. Meaning: In the time that i pushes until the release, the script only gets to show the picture, and the "waitKey" command and beyound dosent execute. Because its set back to "True". But i need it to finish

Heres the code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import cv2
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(17)
    if input_state == False:
    print('Button Pressed')
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    capture.set(3,1280)
    capture.set(4,1024)
    ret, img = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("input", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1500)
    del(capture)
    cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
```

Comment: Is the indentation in your question correct? I cannot determine what that lonely `if` line is doing.

Comment: Currently it is doing nothing. That's why I asked.

Comment: put abother while there instead of an if. while input_state read-input, so once it is false it will end the loop and continue with the following code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, the code after `if` statement is not properly indented.

try using the formatted one below.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import cv2
import os    
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)    
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(17)
    if not input_state: # not False = True
        print('Button Pressed')
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        capture.set(3,1280)
        capture.set(4,1024)
        ret, img = capture.read()
        cv2.imshow("input", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1500)
        del(capture)
        cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
        input_state = True
```

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge changed :)

Comment: Add `input_state = True` at the end of the code and check it now.

Comment: @SimonBjørkvig what happened? Any results?.

Comment: Hi mitty, Still same, no change. Image shows, and keep showing. Just for info: If i isolate the part with camera script, in new script and runs it, it works. Meaning, the camera takes a picture, shows in a window, and close again After 1,5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Im not a python coder so not sure about the syntax:

try this code: Instead of a single if statement, loop until the condition holds.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import cv2
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(17)
    while input_state:
        input_state = GPIO.input(17)
    print('Button Pressed')
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    capture.set(3,1280)
    capture.set(4,1024)
    ret, img = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("input", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1500)
    del(capture)
    cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
```

Comment: No change, still the same. Picture shows in a seperate window and dosent close again. If i press button a new picture in same window comes.

Comment: what behaviour do you want/expect? you'll have to close the window manually: cv.DestroyWindow(name)